# Asking user for a input then display it according to the number of input. Storing and returning the input.in Python

Tags: python

Can someone please help me figure this out in Python? Thank you so much!

Here's the problem I'm having a hard time with.

---

What is on your shopping list today?  (say user input is: pen, book, folder. I want it to duplicate output that will ask a question for each answer.)

What is the estimated cost for pen? 
 Enter estimated cost here:
What is the estimated cost for book? 
 Enter estimated cost here:
What is the estimated cost for folder? 
 Enter estimated cost here:

Total estimated cost for pen, book, folder is: $xx.xx

---

I hope this was not too confusing to explain. Thanks for the help!

Comment: what have you tried and where are you stuck ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python3, it can be done by the following.

```
items_str = input('What is on your shopping list today? (Enter elements separated by a comma) ') #take input from the user
items = items_str.replace(" ", "") #to remove whitespaces
items = items.split(',') #creating an array of the items
total = 0
for item in items:
    total = total + int(input("What is the estimated cost for {0}? Enter estimated cost here: ".format(item)))
print("Total estimated cost for ", items_str, " is ", total)
```